# Separating 50 duplicate points by limit in buffer zone using QGIS

Tags: qgis-3, point, duplication

I am building a customer database in QGIS. I get GPS coordinates for customers from my staff. Then I convert those GPS coordinates into shapefile points in QGIS. I get a lot of duplicate points. I am sure that those are customers that are close together, e.g. house No.54, house No.55, House No.56.

[image]

How do I separate these duplicate points using QGIS?

Comment: What do you mean by limit in the buffer zone? Also in which format you have the data? is it a shapefile, a spatial table or what?

Comment: What do you mean "separate" those points? did you mean cluster closer points into one?

Comment: @eth4io Many points are in the same place (duplicate), I want to separate them.

Comment: Okay I think I got what you mean, so you want to assign those points a random coordinate around their original location and with no overlapping?

Comment: @eth4io That right

Comment: How do you want to "separate" them? Like following what pattern? For example, it can be a circle around the original point (same distance for all points)

Comment: My idea is suppose we have 1 circle, the random distribution points in it. I'm looking for a tool for this idea.

Comment: I know that we can change coordinates by excel but it's very pale.